# Can Salesforce Internal Org Domain be completely custom?

Tags: custom, domain, suffix

My client required to have internal org served not from Salesforce subdomain like `client.my.salesforce.com` but like `client.com`.

Looks like this is not possible, but how should I explain this to my customer?

Comment: I'm assuming this is not an Experience site?

Comment: no, we have contacted Account Manager for a call to discuss if SF can make an exception for our customer but AE hasn't replied to us yet

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if my client were buying Government Cloud, it might have been possible to change to some different suffix
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390226&type=1

but still the domain would be something like `client.my.salesforce.gov` or `client.my.salesforce.inc` but not like `client.com`